# JNA - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

Tags: java, native, jna

I am trying to use JNA to use a method in c# dll.

Java Code -

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

class JNIDemoResource {
  public static interface JNITestInterface extends Library {
    //System.out.println("TCEnabled="+inst.TCEnabled());
    JNITestInterface inst =  (JNITestInterface) Native.loadLibrary("ClassLibrary1", JNITestInterface.class);
    int _Add(int x, int y);
    boolean Flag();
    int Add2(String string, String string2);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "C:\\NativeDll");
    int sum = JNITestInterface.inst._Add(2, 3);
    System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
  }
}
```

C# dll code. I am using the [DllExport nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports#readme-body-tab) in my project to expose the methods in dll.
[image: DLLExport download screencap]

```cs
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [DllExport]
        public static int _Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
        [DllExport]
        public static bool _Flag()
        {
              return true;
        }
    }
}
```

From dependency walker I am able to see the methods in the dll. Dumpbin is also showing that methods are exposed.

```
> dumpbin /exports "C:\NativeDll\ClassLibrary1.dll"

Dump of file C:\NativeDll\ClassLibrary1.dll

  Section contains the following exports for \ClassLibrary1.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    645CBF04 time date stamp Thu May 11 15:40:12 2023
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           2 number of functions
           2 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 0000251A _Add
          2    1 00002526 _Flag

  Summary

        2000 .reloc
        2000 .rsrc
        2000 .sdata
        2000 .text
```

When I am calling the dll method from Java code, I am getting following error -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeInt(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:426)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:361)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:270)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0._Add(Unknown Source)
    at JNIDemoResource.main(JNIDemoResource.java:27)
```

Can anyone please suggest where am I going wrong?

The library that I am using is - jna-5.13.0.jar.

Comment: "Invalid memory access" often comes from invalid type mapping, aka the java method signature not matching up with the one from the native library below. Are you sure that the c# method signature is actually (II)I and doesn't contain some weird microsoft related `int` clone?

Comment: I don't see `int Add2(String string, String string2);` in your C#... why are you specifying *extra* methods? Also, it's `boolean Flag();` one place and `boolean _Flag();` the other.

Answer (score 0):

Your type mappings and function mappings look correct. While there's a mismatch in the functions in your question, they would result in a different error.  The Invalid memory access points to a problem with passing the function and its arguments on the stack.

Possible culprits include:

- function pointer bitness mismatch if you compiled the DLL for a different bitness than your JVM
- calling convention mismatch
- stack is corrupted by a previous call

The [Unmanaged Exports](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports#readme-body-tab) package you are using gives two hints you can follow which correspond to these possible issues:

> - You have to set your platform target to either x86, ia64 or x64. AnyCPU assemblies cannot export functions.

Make sure you are calling from the same bitness of JVM you are running.

> - The export name defaults to the method name and the calling convention to stdcall. If that's all what you want, you can just use [DllExport] without parameters.

You are basically calling `[DllExport("_Add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]`.  However, the JNA invocation passes "this": `Native.invokeInt(this, this.peer, callFlags, args)` so you probably need the [`.ThisCall` convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention?view=net-7.0):

> The first parameter is the `this` pointer and is stored in register ECX. Other parameters are pushed on the stack. This calling convention is used to call methods on classes exported from an unmanaged DLL.

As an (easier) alternative to changing your DLL export to conform to JNA's expected convention, you can also use the Library loading options when you load the DLL to tell JNA which conventions to use.  While there are many ways to do this, these seem the easiest (pick one):

- add the appropriate convention in the loading options
- add an `implements AltCallingConvention`
- replace your implementation of `Library` with `StdCallLibrary`

Finally, you may be looking in the wrong place for the error.  You could have corrupted the stack with a previous function call.  Since your question includes a mismatch with function names between C and Java (`Flag()` without the underscore, and an `Add2()` method) it's clear that the bits of code you are showing us are not the complete class files.  Look at any method mappings that you call before `_Add()`, it's entirely possible you've created the error there.

Comment: I tried 2 approaches  - 
1. build the code in 32bit and 64 bit both for dll and java. Still no luck.
2. Tried to put explicit export statement - [DllExport( CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
 
Still no luck.. Any help here..

Comment: @sumansourav did you try changing the JNA inheritance to `StdCallLibrary`?

Comment: @sumansourav your `_Add()` method may be properly mapped but the error/stack corruption could be in a different mapping that you call first.  As you have a mismatch between the methods you've shown in C and Java, I am not confident you have shown us all the code involved here.  Please double-check all your function names and mappings.

Comment: The issue was because of the .net framework version. The dll was built out of 6.2 version. I build the dll on 4.6 and it worked.

Comment: Now, since this was just a simple add method, it was fine. But the actual requirement is to call a DLL which in turn calls other DLLs, make a db connection, and return me the decrypted password. But the JNA Library throws a memory invalid issue whenever it tries to load the global variables in dll or call another method from the invoked method. So, is it possible to use JNA for calling a dll that in turn calls other dlls and makes a DB connection??

Comment: Does JNA support calling another DLL from the main DLL? The use case is  - we have a DLL exposed to Java and this DLL is calling multiple other DLLs to fetch the result. Is this a case supported by this library? If yes, do we have any references?  And do all the DLLs require  [DllExport] tag to be specified in all or invoked method as part of the execution flow across all the internal chained DLLs.

Comment: @sumansourav The question "does it support" seems out of context here. Yes, if a DLL calls another that can work with JNA, but JNA doesn't do anything special to enable this.  Without a speicific example this question os way too broad to answer.

Comment: So the use case is - We have one DLL with emaildecryption method that we are using to invoke through Java using JNA.  The parent DLL that is used with [DllExport] tag internally calls 12 other DLLs to decrypt the email address of a user. The other 12 DLLs can not be modified as these are security-related DLLs.  So, can we use JNA to call a DLL that internally calls other DLLs without making any change in the dependent DLLs? Can we achieve this? OS - 64-bit Windows, DLLs compiled from .net 4.6 , Java - 1.8.  (Parent DLL - EmailProcs.dll with [DLLExport] method)

Comment: @sumansourav yes, so long as the dependent DLLs are accessible to search